# bash, substitute part of variable by another variable

Tags: bash, substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

SUNDAY_MENU=BREAD
MONDAY_MENU=APPLES

TODAY=MONDAY


ECHO "I want ${${TODAY}_MENU}" # does not work, bad substitution

ECHO "I want ${`echo $TODAY`_MENU}" # does not work, bad substitution
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Use [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection) like this:

```
varname=${TODAY}_MENU
echo ${!varname}
```

If you are using Bash 4 or later, however, you are probably better off using an [associative array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays):

```
menu=([sunday]=bread [monday]=apples)
echo ${menu[$TODAY]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use eval function

```
#!/bin/bash

SUNDAY_MENU=BREAD
MONDAY_MENU=APPLES

TODAY=MONDAY

eval TODAY_MENU=\$\{${TODAY}_MENU\}

echo "I want ${TODAY_MENU}"
```